# How to log the summary report when starting the test from command line

Tags: jmeter

I'm starting the test from command line. Is there any way in which i can produce log file in the same form as the summary report listener from GUI mode ?

Answer (score 7):

Your question contains the answer.

Just [run JMeter in non-GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) mode as per guide.

```
jmeter -n -t D:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl
```

After that

- Open JMeter GUI (you may not choose any test plan at all)
- Add [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) Listener
- In Filename -> Browse - > D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl

Voila, you now have summary results.

Another option is using a [JMeter Cloud Plugin](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter) which generates not only summary report, but produces informative and professional-looking graphs which help in load test results analysis and has different test run results comparison feature.

Check [sample report](https://a.blazemeter.com/report/r-ec528242f1e891d) if you're interested.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without opening the JMeter GUI?

Comment: It is, check out [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which is capable of generating different types of reports and charts in non-GUI mode. You can install the tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: There is no way to do it from JMeter itself?  It requires a separate tool?

Comment: Starting from [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) you have [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which comes with [Statistics Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/dashboard/report_statistics.png) which appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: is the Statistics Table also output in CSV format?